# Hiding elements in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have defined a XAML page for my WP8 app that currently holds a `LongListSelector` with an `ItemTemplate`.

I'm outputting some personal info like name and age. Each is a `TextBlock` defined like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Age, StringFormat='Age: {0}'}" Visibility="{Binding AgeVisibility}"/>
```

The thing is that the user doesn't always input all the data, so sometimes some attributes are missing (like age). In those cases I would like to **remove** the `TextBlock`.

With the code defined like it is (note the use of the `Visibility` attribute) it only **hides** the element, which leaves an ugly space in the form.

Is there a way to remove an element from the list, if it might be undefined/missing?

**EDIT:** I should note that while I *do* use a `LongListSelector`, it only actually holds a *single* element. This element is then binded to a pure data class with many properties:

```
public class Details
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating an `ObservableCollection` of objects you'd like to bind, and adding it to the `LongListSelector` like this:

`longListSelector.ItemsSource = myCollection;`.

Everytime you'd like to remove an element from the list, you'd just call something like `myCollection.RemoveAt(0)` and the list will update itself.

Comment: I've updated the question, since I've badly explained my situation: my list only holds one data object (which has many properties that are binded in XAML). Do you recommend I don't use the pure data object, and instead use an `ObserverCollection` of strings?

Comment: I could be wrong, and there could be a better solution. I've used a LongListSelector with custom a ItemTemplate for a couple of times for binding multiple objects. I would recommend that if you already have a List of pure data objects, to just change from List to ObservableCollection, and then add it to the LongListSelector ItemsSource property.